# Let $A$ be a ring, and $I$ be an ideal of $A$, then $ AI＝I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $A$ be a ring, and $I$ be an ideal of $A$, then is $ AI＝I$ true?

Here, $AI$ means the product as ideals.

Does this holds when we change product as sets, that is, $A・I＝I$?

Sorry to ask very basic question, thank you in advance.

Comment: What definition of "ideal" are you using?  I'm used to the answer to your first question being part of that definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $AI$ is equal to the additive subgroup of $A$ generated by $A{\cdot}I=\{ax\mid a\in A,x\in I\}$ (let me know if I am misreading your notation).

By definition of an ideal we have $A{\cdot}I\subseteq I$, and then because $I$ is an additive subgroup you also get $AI\subseteq I$.

If $A$ is a unital ring then equality always holds, because for $x\in I$ you have $x=1_A{\cdot}x\in A{\cdot}I$.

On the other hand equality may not hold if the ring is not unital: for instance if you take $A=2\mathbb Z$ and $I=4\mathbb Z$ then $A{\cdot}I=AI=8\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's what I was liking for! I understand A・I＝I and AI＝I both holds.But why can I say A・I⊂AI？（If we cannot say that, we can only say AI⊂I）

Comment: What is $AI$ by definition? Tell me if your definition differs, but for me $AI=\{\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_i\mid n\in\mathbb N,a_i\in A,x_i\in I\}$.

Comment: If you agree with this definition then for $ax\in A{\cdot}I$ we clearly have $ax\in AI$.

Comment: Thaa's exactly my definiton, thank you. Then, we can write down the definition of ideal I of A, like subset of A which satisfies $ I＋I＝I and IR＝I$, is this correct?